# Separate data into multiple time series R

Tags: r, excel

I have a single excel sheet with all of the states in the united states. I would like to create a time series out of each state and have the data frequency be daily (it is currently by minute). The most I have done so far was to delete all of the excess columns but I am having trouble thinking of an efficient way to make the data daily and separated by state without doing it manually.

I hope to use ggplot with all of these new time series. I tried using the melt function and gather function but both did not work.

Here is a portion of my data:

[image]
Where the state column goes from 1-51 and the dates are repeated every now and then since its frequency was per minute. I would like to ultimiatley create a time series for each of these states so I could analyze them side by side. Some states may not have data records for everyday, how do I fill in those dates automatically with zero?

Comment: And how should daily values be calculated? Say, should all VE_TOTALS, VE_FORMS, etc.. be summed by State/day?

Comment: Yes! but each column separate so that I could see which of the columns have the most meaningful value and choose that. But I would like them to be totaled by @NicolásVelásquez

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, Cherry. In the future, please provide a reproducible example rather than a picture of a data frame. The function `dput(your_df_here)` might be useful.

Here is my sample data, which is different from your:

```
df <- structure(list(STATE = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), VETOTAL = c(2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2), VEFORMS = c(2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2), 
           PVHJNVL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PEDS = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), PERSONS = c(3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2), 
           PERMVIT = c(3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2), PERNOTMVI = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), COUNTY = c(81, 55, 29, 55, 3, 85), 
           CITY = c(2340, 1280, 0, 2562, 0, 0), DAY = c(7, 23, 22, 7, 23, 22), MONTH = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), 
           YEAR = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), FATALS = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), DRUNK_DR = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)), 
       row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is how, with the help of `{tidyverse}` we create a date observation,  group by State and date, and then summarise a sum.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(date = as.Date(paste(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, sep = "-"))) %>% # create a date
   group_by(STATE, date) %>% # Group by State id and date
   summarise_at(.vars = vars(VETOTAL:PERNOTMVI, FATALS, DRUNK_DR), sum) ## Summarise a sum of those variables between VETOTAL and PERNOTMVI, plus FATALS and DRUNK_DR
```

### Results:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 10
# Groups:   STATE [2]
  STATE date       VETOTAL VEFORMS PVHJNVL  PEDS PERSONS PERMVIT PERNOTMVI FATALS
  <dbl> <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 2019-01-22       3       3       0     0       4       4         0      1
2     1 2019-01-23       2       2       0     0       2       2         0      1
3     1 2019-02-07       2       2       0     0       3       3         0      1
4     2 2019-01-22       2       2       0     0       2       2         0      1
5     2 2019-01-23       1       1       0     0       1       1         0      0
6     2 2019-02-07       1       1       0     1       1       1         1      1
```

### Filling missing dates.

If you want to fill with 0 the values of missing dates within a range (i.e. those dates without recorded observations), we can do so with the help of `{padr}`

```
library(padr)
    df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, sep = "-"))) %>% 
  group_by(STATE, date) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = vars(VETOTAL:PERNOTMVI, FATALS), sum) %>% 
  padr::pad(start_val = min(.$date), #This sets the start value as the earliest date present in the "date" variable 
            end_val = max(.$date)) %>%    #This sets the end value as the earliest date present in the "date" variable
  fill_by_value(value = 0)
```

### Results:

```
# A tibble: 34 x 10
# Groups:   STATE [2]
   STATE date       VETOTAL VEFORMS PVHJNVL  PEDS PERSONS PERMVIT PERNOTMVI FATALS
   <dbl> <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1 2019-01-22       3       3       0     0       4       4         0      1
 2     1 2019-01-23       2       2       0     0       2       2         0      1
 3     1 2019-01-24       0       0       0     0       0       0         0      0
 4     1 2019-01-25       0       0       0     0       0       0         0      0
 5     1 2019-01-26       0       0       0     0       0       0         0      0
 6     1 2019-01-27       0       0       0     0       0       0         0      0
 7     1 2019-01-28       0       0       0     0       0       0         0      0
 8     1 2019-01-29       0       0       0     0       0       0         0      0
 9     1 2019-01-30       0       0       0     0       0       0         0      0
10     1 2019-01-31       0       0       0     0       0       0         0      0
# ... with 24 more rows
```

Comment: I will make sure to use that function next time! Thank you! Although, I have a question. If I wanted to make this into a time series I know to use df_ts=ts(df$'STATE',freq=365,start=c(2019,1)) lets say. But in the sample data you gave me, it still shows a state like state 1 multiple times for the same date. Is there a way to combine lets say your first and fourth row? So that it is one state's values printed for one date with respect to ve_total, veform etc? @NicolásVelásquez

Comment: I think I did that in the group_by() and summarise_at() lines.
Take a look at how row 1 lists `STATE` == 1, while row 4 lists `STATE` == 2.

Comment: oh my yes, I was looking at two different states you're right. SO now, if I add the section to your code that is: %>% filter(STATE=='1') I see that I get 325 rows back which is odd because shoudn't it be 365? Because if I try to go forth with creating my time series, writing 
 state1_ts=ts(state1$'VE_TOTAL', freq=365, start=c(2019,1)) I get back an odd two column set. or maybe filtering by state didn't make sense since I want one time series for each state. Sorry still a bit lost @Nicolás Velásquez

Comment: Hi Cherry. My guess is that State #1 only had records for 325 out of 365 days. I guess that such a State was not Florida, because I used to see accidents from my window every single day. If you need to fill with 0 the days without incidents, please add the request to your post.

Comment: Haha, you should be in charge of Floridas crash data then! I will add it now.@Nicolás Velásquez

Comment: Done. Do note that you might want to select other values for `pad()`'s `start_val` and `end_val`. In my example, I used the minimum and maximum dates in the table, but you might have other dates in mind. Simply add them within an `as.Date()` , i.e. `start_val = as.Date('2000-01-01')`

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help! Such an amazing platform Stack Overflow is. Just as a general questions, for the line of code that has the summaris_at function, am allowed to change sum to whatever aggregate function I like(var, std,max)? Also, is there a reason you have VETOTAL:PERNOTMVI, FATALS and not just a list of the column names?Lastly, when I come to make my time series, is it okay for me to label the code above as states and then create a time series out of that? Or I need to redo this step and filter by each state, and then create the ts from filtered data. @Nicolás Velásquez

Comment: Yes, summarise_at will accept all functions that process a single variable on its own. 
I write VETOTAL:PERNOTMVI for economy of typing, but it gets the eqivalent to  `c(VETOTAL, VEFORMS, PVHJNVL, PEDS,  PERSONS, PERMVIT, PERNOTMVI)` 
Regarding the time-series object and grouping, I am not certain. Which package are you using for the time series?
If you are using stats::st() to do so, the grouping will disappear from the ts() object. So it depends on what you need to do.

Comment: I have created a new thread since I got an alert this one was too long! Although, I just realized that your dataset correction added states thats weren't there so I am lost again. My original data had 51 states but it shows 56 @Nicolás Velásquez https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640975/plot-multiple-time-series-together-that-have-a-changed-frequencyunder-one-excel